# Structuring a laravel subquery

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have an events table linked to a locations table (with lng/lat) and need to return the events near a certain location.

I have used a subquery to find the locations within a certain distance ($distance) which seems to work fine. 
I am struggling to include the computed distance in the results.

I think I need to use something like `select('*', [calculated distance] as $distance)->where(bla bla)` in the subquery but can seem to make it work and access it from the collection.

The code below works but I would like all the calculated distances to be available.

```
$events = Event::with('location')
->whereHas('location', function($q) use ($user_lat, $user_lng, $max_distance)
{
    $q->where(\DB::raw('3959 * acos(cos(radians('. $user_lat .')) * cos(radians(location_latitude)) * cos(radians(location_longitude) - radians('. $user_lng .')) + sin(radians('. $user_lat .')) * sin(radians(location_latitude)))'), '<', $max_distance);
})
->get();
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Calculating the distance using SQL functions inside the whereClause would only filter the results, you'd need a leftJoin to include the computed distance

Comment: Creating a database view and querying the view seems like the solution with least hassle and maximum benefit. Instead of forcing SQL to play with Eloquent, why not create a view which will appear as a table to Eloquent? Your problem gets hugely reduced.

Comment: Thanks guys. Perhaps a view is the best way to go. Any thoughts about the security of using a view in Laravel? Seems like it has to be accessed on a raw SQL basis eg.  $rows = \DB::select('select * from eventlocation');